# Item is undefined when using SPServices to fetch items from Sharepoint list

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, spservices

I am trying to fetch all items from the SharePoint list if the column value contains "Some Value". The item count I am getting is correct, however my items object "liHtml" always is returning undefined.

```
   <script language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script language="javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   $(document).ready(function() {
    GetAllListItem();
    });
    function GetAllListItem()
    {
     $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: "TestList",
        CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ServerStatus' /><Value Type='Text'>Some value</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
          $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {      
            var liHtml = "<li>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
           alert(liHtml);
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <script language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script language="javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>



$(document).ready(function() {
GetAllListItem();
});
function GetAllListItem()
{
 $().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    async: false,
    listName: "TestList",
    CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ServerStatus' /><Value Type='Text'>Some value</Value></Eq></Where></Query>",
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
      $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(node) {      
        var liHtml = "<li>" + $(node).attr("ows_Title") + "</li>";
       alert(liHtml);
      });
    }
  });
}
```